# Sync S3 bucket to local machine but delete local objects that have been moved to glacier storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a script that I run on a cron to sync an S3 bucket to my local machine:

```
LOCAL_DATA_PATH=~/Data/my/local/data/path
S3_BUCKET_PATH=s3://my-data-bucket/and/path

aws s3 sync --delete --exclude "*_ignore-me_*" $S3_BUCKET_PATH $LOCAL_DATA_PATH
```

This is great except that my hard drive is filling up. In AWS, I have machinery that automatically glaciates certain files once they become outdated. How can I modify my `sync` command to automatically remove those glaciated files from my local machine? It appears that the files, though stored in glacier, still show up in the metadata and therefore aren't removed via the `--delete` option. I do notice, however, that on a fresh run to an empty local directory, the glacier-stored files are ignored.

Alternatively, is there another command that can clear out any glacier-stored files from my local directory? I think this could work too because, as I say, sync doesn't download glacier-stored files.

Answer (score 1):

CLI command [`aws s3api list-objects-v2`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) supports the `--query` option, and the response contains storage class information. So you could do something like this:

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='GLACIER']" --bucket yourbucket`

to get a list of Glacier objects. You could then extract the keys from the response and delete any matching files on your local drive.

Note that if you have a large number of objects, `list-objects-v2` could time out or take a long time to execute. If you want to do this periodically - once a week, say - it might be more efficient to generate an [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) for your bucket, then write a shell script to download that once a week, filter it to the Glacier objects, and use that to delete local files.